# filecount in Rust

Tags: python, rust

I have this python code and I am trying to recreate this in rust:

```py
filecount = 0
while True:
    with open(f"file{filecount}.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write("Hello World")
        file.close()
        filecount += 1
```

in Rust I try this but I get something about enum error when compiling.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut filecount = 0;
    while True {
        let mut file = File::create("file{}.txt", filecount)?;
        file.write_all(b"Hello, world!")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? (edit into the post. Also format the error message as code)

Comment: I am trying to include the error, but Stackoverflow tells me "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: You can try to post the first few lines of the error message; or add a few lines of explanation about what the code does. Fix the one that you can fix yourself first.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8qQ0Gmbg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at the error messages one by one.

`True` exists in Python but Rust expects `true`; by the way, in Rust an infinite loop is `loop { ... }`.
You forgot to increment `filecount`; a `for` (infinite or not) could take care of this.

You are using the file name in `create()` as a formatting operation.
You should prepare `let name = format!("file{}.txt", filecount);` before calling `create()`.

The `Ok(())` you wrote is supposed to represent the return value of the
whole function (once the loop is done) but you put it inside the loop.
Then at the end of this function `()` is implicitly returned, which does not match with the expected result type.

Here is a minimal attempt to adjust your code example.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    // count from 0 to infinity,  0..5 would be more reasonable
    for filecount in 0.. {
        let name = format!("file{}.txt", filecount);
        let mut file = File::create(name)?;
        file.write_all(b"Hello, world!")?;
        if filecount > 4 {
            // I don't want to fill up my filesystem but your
            // original example creates an infinite number of files
            break;
        }
    }
    Ok(()) // return success at the end of the loop
}
```